# JS - How to add an onclick event to a div with parameter?

Tags: javascript

I know how to add an onclick event to a div without parameter :

```
newDiv.onclick = selectUnit;

function selectUnit() {}
```

But I could not make it work with parameters :

```
function appendUnit(nb) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    newDiv.id = "unit" + nb;
    newDiv.onclick = selectUnit(this.id); // This throws me undefined
    document.getElementById("unitsList").appendChild(newDiv);
}

function selectUnit(id) {
    console.debug(id);
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: can you specify when `appendUnit` is called?

Comment: `<div id="buy" class="actionButton" onclick="buyUnit()">Buy</div>` buyUnit() function call appendUnit().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need an anonymous function for that, as there is no way to pass arguments to a referenced function

```
function appendUnit() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    newDiv.onclick = function() {
        selectUnit(this.id);
    }

    document.getElementById("unitsList").appendChild(newDiv);
}

function selectUnit(id) {
    console.debug(id);
}
```

but note that the value of `this` will keep, so you can do

```
function appendUnit() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    newDiv.onclick = selectUnit;

    document.getElementById("unitsList").appendChild(newDiv);
}

function selectUnit() {
    console.debug( this.id ); // this is still the same here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With that line of code

```
newDiv.onclick = selectUnit(this.id);
```

you just call the function, get its result and store it to the onclick handler.

A function with no return defined inside returns undefined.
The `this.id` will refer to the `this` element you currently have at your scope which may be the `window` object.

When the onclick happens, somewhere chrome will call this function

```
DOMElement.onclick(EventObject);
```

And with your line it will be something like this

```
(undefined)(this.id);
```

which leads to errors

All you have to do is to set onclick with a method

```
newDiv.onclick = selectUnit;
```

And chrome will call this

```
DOMElement.onclick(EventObject);
```

Having `DOMElement.onclick == selectUnit` we can assume the upper line of code is similar to this:

```
selectUnit(EventObject);
```

Then on your `selectUnit` function you must know how to access the `id`. You can see at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event what you can do with it. So the new `selectUnit` function will be:

```
function selectUnit(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    console.debug(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set the id in your example code:

```
function appendUnit() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "somevalue";

    [...]
    newDiv.onclick = "selectUnit(this.id);" // This throws me undefined
    document.getElementById("unitsList").appendChild(newDiv);
}

function selectUnit(id) {
    console.debug(id);
}
```

Comment: I do in the real code, I edited my post. But your code doesn't work. You pointed the problem, `this` refers to the function not the div at this moment. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Try adding quotes around your onclick event.  I just edited the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function appendUnit() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    [...]
    newDiv.onclick = function(){
        selectUnit(this.id); // This throws me undefined
    }
    document.getElementById("unitsList").appendChild(newDiv);
}
```